# Realizar una condición con ciertas reglas en el archivo .htaccess para páginas no encontradas

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error404

Necesito crear algunas reglas en al archivo **.htaccess** para que se den ciertas condiciones. Por ejemplo, quiero mostrar el archivo **404.shtml** (`ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml`) **sólo en el caso en donde la URL generada tenga la extensión .html o .php** (cuando este mal escrita claro o no la encuentre en mi sitio), en los otros casos no (que es cuando la página se comporta como SPA).

Al ser SPA (single-page application), trabaja siempre sobre la misma página y aquí **no necesito que se vea el archivo 404.shtml**. Entonces tengo lo siguiente y que ya está funcionando:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Ahora quiero el caso contrario **cuando no está en la página de tipo SPA**. Necesitaría alguna regla para que se vea la página *404.shtml*, cuando ya son las otras páginas internas y que **siempre llevan la extensión .html o .php.** y no están en el sitio (página no encontrada).

Sólo a modo de ejemplo, sería algo así:

```
IF (la pagina es SPA){
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
} else {
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
}
```

En este momento lo tengo así en el archivo **.htaccess**:

```
...
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
```

... pero el 404.shtml nunca se genera cuando la página no existe.

En definitiva, necesito que, si la URL está dentro de las manejadas por el SPA, se redirija a la SPA y en otro caso se redirija a una página *404.shtml*

¿Se puede hacer algo parecido a esto desde el archivo **.htaccess**?

Comment: las primeras 3 reglas indican que si el archivo no existe ( sin tamaño, no es symlink, no es carpeta ) entonces es index.php el que se hace cargo de procesar la petición, a partir de ahí si index.php se comporta como SPA, o es un CMS, o framework, es responsabilidad de index.php mostrar el 404 cuando no reconozca la ruta

Comment: @aloMalbarez Entonces, no comprendo lo que me dices. En realidad, sólo me describes lo que hacen esas líneas.¿Tu dices que lo que tengo debería funcionar para el 404? Porque no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que si el documento existe y tiene extensión `*.php` o `*.html` te redirija a página no encontrada? ¿Exista o no exista realmente el archivo o sólo si tiene esas extensiones **Y** existe el archivo?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Se trata **solamente** de que cuando la página no existe y donde la extensión es **.html** o **.php** (que es cuando vienen las páginas del sitio que están en carpetas: /biografías, /historias…etc.).
Por ejemplo la URL _https://www.ejemplo.com/biografías/Blaise_Pascal.html_ estaría bien, pero _https://www.ejemplo.com/biografías/Blaise_Pascall.html_ o _https://www.ejemplo.com/historias/biografías/Blaise_Pascal.html_ estarían mal y acá quiero que se muestra la página 404. Quizas hay una forma de hacer alguna condición.

Comment: En el caso de que la "inteligencia" de qué página existe y cuál no esté en la SPA entonces no puedes programar el 404 en el servidor Apache. El servidor Apache tiene conocimiento de los archivos de tu página, pero no es capaz de hacer consultas a la base de datos para saber si un artículo debería existir o no. Lo que sí que se puede hacer es que si en ciertos directorios (como `/biografías/*`) sólo hay archivos que no forman parte del SPA, entoces de pueden excluir de la regla del SPA para que generen el error 404. Si eso es así dímelo para indicarte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Exactamente esas carpetas no forman parte del SPA y es allí donde quiero generar el error 404. Yo decía lo de .html o.php, porque no se me ocurría otra opción para diferenciarlas con las de SPA. Pero lo de ir verificando los directorios puede funcionar, lo que sí es que tengo varios directorios. Espero me indiques como se hace entonces.

Comment: Redactando respuesta, dame unos minutos.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar si mi respuesta soluciona tu problema? Si quieres puedo hacerte un ejemplo usando las extensiones como inicialmente propusiste.

Comment: Si, pasa que estaba revisando diferentes URLs para ver como se comportaba. La verdad funciona pero no al 100 %.
Es que por ejemplo, estaba viendo unas URLs que me genera Google (no entiendo porque) desde Analytics, la cual es:
_https://www.glosarioit.com/Módem/historias/biografías/virus/Onda_electromagnética_ (no quería que se vea mi web, pero para que se entienda es mejor).
Y en este ejemplo te das cuenta que **no sale la página 404** y eso que allí está /biografías, /historias, /virus. Quizás debería buscar en toda la URL esas carpetas.

Comment: Si quitas la palabra /Módem de la URL funciona y me tira el error 404 con la página.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Sólo decir que saque el carácter **^** de la condición (porque las carpetas a veces aparecen en cualquier lado y no sólo al comienzo). Con esto ya quedaría, gracias y pongo tu solución como respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solución propuesta

Para solucionar tu problema basta con excluir de la regla los directorios reales que tengas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Excluimos (!) todo lo que empiece por las rutas deseadas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/biografía/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/historias/
# Excluimos (!) todo lo que termine en .html o .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
# Si todas las condiciones se cumplen, apoyamos el SPA
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

También se puede hacer con una única condición por cada comprobación:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(biografía|historias)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html)$
```

### Documentación

El funcionamiento de [`RewriteCond`/`REQUEST_URI`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> **`REQUEST_URI`**
>
> The path component of the requested URI, such as `/index.html`. This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named `QUERY_STRING`.

En castellano:

> **`REQUEST_URI`**
>
> La componente de la ruta de la URI solicitada, como `/index.html`. Esto excluye deliveradamente la cadena de consulta que está disponible como variable independiente llamada `QUERY_STRING`.

### Pruebas

Creamos los siguientes archivos:

```
.htaccess
historias/otra.html
biografía/pruebas.html
pruebas/primera.html
pruebas/segunda.php
pruebas/tercera.txt
```

- `http://url/.htaccess`: generará un `Forbidden` por las reglas de seguridad por defecto del servidor Apache.
- `http://url/historias/otra.html`: Cargará el archivo HTML (reglas de directorio).
- `http://url/biografía/pruebas.html`: Cargará el archivo HTML (reglas de directorio).
- `http://url/pruebas/primera.html`: Cargará el archivo HTML (reglas de extensión de archivo).
- `http://url/pruebas/segunda.php`: Cargará y ejecutará el script PHP (reglas de extensión de archivo).
- `http://url/pruebas/tercera.txt`: Pasará al SPA.
- `http://url/pruebas/cuarta.html`: Generará un error 404 (las reglas de extensión de archivo impiden el SPA).